# Javascript after generating dynamic field name its not working

Tags: javascript

I have one form in this

```
<td style="width:100px;">
  <input type="radio" name="smart_offer_status_1" onclick="show_layer('smart_offer_form_1');">Yes&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="smart_offer_status_1" onclick="hide_layer('smart_offer_form_1');">No
</td>
```

I want to check that any of above firelds are checked or not so on form submit I created one function but it says that undefined variable

```
var current_display_offers = [1,4];
function formvalidate()
{
    var radio_button_error = 0;

    for(var i=0;i < current_display_offers.length;i++)
    {
        var radio_button_yes = "smart_offer_status_"+current_display_offers[i]+"[0].checked";
        var radio_button_no = "smart_offer_status_"+current_display_offers[i]+"[1].checked";
        var a = current_display_offers[i];



        if(document.offer_form.radio_button_yes==false && document.offer_form.radio_button_no==false)
        {   
            alert('hi');
        }

    }
    alert(radio_button_error);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How should that work? You include `[1].checked` in the name of the form element?

Comment: Please check my above description I included [0] and [1] because I have two radio buttons with same name.

Comment: Okay, but how does the `.checked` belongs to the name?

Comment: @idmean : I am generating dynamic field name that's why java script not  says that "undefined"

Comment: But `.checked` does not belong to the name, does it? Your string may only contain the **name** of the radio button, not any JavaScript properties (`.checked`). If you want to use this string to access the form you need to use `[]` like `document.offer_form[radio_button_yes]`. You should probably refresh some basic JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the text only in the name of the form element. remove `[0]` and `.checked` when generating the name.

*Use*

```
//Generate dynamic text
var radio_button_yes = "smart_offer_"+current_display_offers[i]+"_status"; //Also remove [0]
var radio_button_no = "smart_offer_"+current_display_offers[i]+"_status";//Also remove [1]

//Access using Bracket notation
//Then use checked property
if(document.offer_form[radio_button_yes][0].checked ==false && document.offer_form[radio_button_no][1].checked ==false)
{   
    alert('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to retrieve the input element :

```
var input1 = document.getElementsByName("smart_offer_status_1");
```

And then you can check if the input is checked :

```
if(input1.checked == true){
//...
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use this code you have to change the name of the input (or add an `id`), in order to retrieve just one `input` when you call `document.getElementsByName("smart_offer_status_1");`

For example :

```
<td style="width:100px;">
  <input type="radio" id"=input1" name="smart_offer_status_1" onclick="show_layer('smart_offer_form_1');">Yes&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id"=input2" name="smart_offer_status_1" onclick="hide_layer('smart_offer_form_1');">No
</td>
```

An here the JavaScript code :

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but I can not use id because this is not only for two radio buttons there is more fields like smart_offer_status_2,smart_offer_status_3 etc

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll delete my post if it's of no use.

Comment: "var input1 = document.getElementsByName("smart_offer_status_1");" this is helpful for me

Comment: Indeed. You can get an array of input and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for answer on my question because of your answer I am able to found my answer.check below

```html
//VALIDATE FORM
function formvalidate()
{
 var radio_button_error = 0;
 
 for(var i=0;i < current_display_offers.length;i++)
 {
  var radio_button = document.getElementsByName("smart_offer_status_"+current_display_offers[i]);
  
  if(radio_button[0].checked ==false && radio_button[1].checked ==false)
  {   
      radio_button_error++;
  }
 }
 alert(radio_button_error);
 return false;
}
```